# How can I preserve an overlay from a Chrome extension through page navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that injects HTML and JS into Web pages to create a sort of three.js 3D scene that contains 3D versions of the page's HTML elements. Right now, I am injecting the 3D scene code as a wrapper into every web page when it loads. Because of this, the 3D scene is destroyed with every link click.

I would like to preserve this 3D scene through page navigation so that when a user clicks a link, the scene remains but the HTML elements are replaced with the new page elements.

Would someone know what direction to go in for this? Thanks!

Comment: Pages are destroyed completely on normal (non-AJAX) navigations so you'll have to re-inject. Is there a problem like slowness or what exactly would you like to enhance?

Comment: This is a VR app running through the extension.  So when a user navigates to a new page, the 3D scene is destroyed along with the web page, and the user is kicked out of the scene until a new page is loaded.  I would like to keep the scene around if possible for a better experience

Comment: No, you'll have to keep it in a new window.